# drop initialize in portlet jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, portlet

im using jquery ui potlet and i need the portles be initialized dropper.
Now when the pages load portles collapse is on mode.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

hi pex im using th default code:

```
$(function() {
        $(".column").sortable({
            connectWith: '.column'
        });

        $(".portlet").addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
            .find(".portlet-header")
                .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
                .prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>')
                .end()
            .find(".portlet-content");

        $(".portlet-header .ui-icon").click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick").toggleClass("ui-icon-plusthick");
            $(this).parents(".portlet:first").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
        });

        $(".column").disableSelection();
    });
```